How to add an image to fit to the exact dimensions of a single face on a rectangle face of box?
I have a 24“ x 48“ image that I want to add to a rectangle box which has dimensions of 24“ x 48“ x 1“ depth. How do I add the 24“ x 48“ to fit exactly to one face of the rectangle?

If you use Blender 4.1 and earlier, you should enable "Import images as planes" add-on in user preferences.
In Blender 4.2 this option enabled by default. Press Shit+A -> Image -> Mesh Plane (Shit+A -> Image -> Images as planes for 4.1)
Set transform mode in Pixels per Inch end set Image DPI.
4.2:

4.1:

Select your image and press Import Images as Planes button.
It will add a plane, that it is easy to add thickness using an Extrude operation.
